# Where should I generate my salt in my AngularJS app

Tags: php, angularjs, salt

I have a AngularJS app and while need to generate a salt for password security purpose. My app doesn't use php since it's AngularJS, but I have a Slim API to access my database. Should I generate the salt in my API with a special function that just receive the password then hash it with the salt before adding my hash and salt to the database?

Comment: Yes.  wait... is this a trick question?  why wouldn't you use your api layer for that?  Its the only place that your end-user won't see the salt you generate (or, the HOW behind that generation).  Not being snotty ... just don't get why this isn't the obvious choice for you.  what are we not seeing??

Comment: I just wanted to really make sure that I got the wright idea since we are talking about password security. On the other hand, I'm not bad with web and server, but it's not my mean vocation as a programmer, so I don't know everything or well enough to totally trust my instinct.

Comment: Trust it.  Don't generate anything realated to encrytion in js ... even if it's "safe" -- it'll smell bad to your dev lead.  Have fun - angular is great to work with btw!

Comment: thanks, you should write an answer so that I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Trust your instinct**

I'd avoid generating anything password/encryption related within the js.  Even if it's minor and "safe" (eg - mostly random), it'll smell bad to your dev lead.

This seems silly.  It really belongs in the comments ;-)